# How to design a MongoDB schema with users, brands and data ownership

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, schema

I'm in the early stages of developing an node.js/react app that helps users manage restaurant food menu data. And now I'm wondering how to best set up the users, restaurant brand account and data ownership.

The users should be individual people and relates to login and authentication.

The brand account should be owned by users, and multiple users should be able to access the brand account data.

The data should be owned by the brand account, and only users with access to that brand should be able to access that data.

What are best practices to handle this in terms of schema relationships?

I'd probably have a User model, an Account model and several other data models. Let's use MenuItems as an example.

Is this the correct approach as a very simplified example?:

```
User {
 email: String,
 password: String
}

Account {
 account_name: String,
 users: [User1, User2 ...] // Embedded docs or references
}

MenuItems {
 title: String,
 description: String,
 account: [Account] // Embedded doc or reference
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, I never know if I have to join or not... Joins seems expensive for MongoDB
For example, if menuItems is different for each users, I would put this array directly in Users. You can then query the field you want with .select https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to join, you should use populate: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```